# varnish cli_buffer value not saved after updated /etc/default/varnish.vcl

Tags: magento, nginx, varnish, varnish-vcl

I have been trying this since yesterday but no success. I have debian 8, nginx and varnish 4.0.2

I want to update varnish cli_buffer value from 8k to 16k. Following is my /etc/varnish/default.vcl configuration.

[default.vcl](http://codepaste.net/wdepwc)

```
DAEMON_OPTS="-a :80 \
         -T localhost:6082 \
         -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl \
         -S /etc/varnish/secret \
     -p cli_buffer=16384 \
     -p feature=+esi_ignore_other_elements \
     -p vcc_allow_inline_c=on \
         -s malloc,256m"
```

I'm lost where to update now. Any suggestions ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

What you are showing is the Varnish daemon options for the file /etc/default/varnish but you seem to have put that information in the /etc/varnish/default.vcl which will not work. The default.vcl file is for the Varnish configuration (not the daemon startup).